# IMAP gmail connection is very slow

Tags: php, performance, gmail, imap

In my CRM online system (made in PHP) I handle IMAP connections. I have problem with gmail... Long times, very long times :/ It always takes 2-4 sec to connect and I cannot speed it up. Somewhere I read that using ip insead of server in imap string {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl} will be good, but there is problem with certificate :/

Does anyone has more ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to put IP to your /etc/hosts file and use hostname.It will skip DNS lookup and directly to IP, but certificate should work.By the way, which functions you're use to access IMAP?

Use this code to ignore certificate problems:

```
imap_open ("{IP_OF_GMAIL:995/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "user_id", "password");
```

Comment: But I have no access to server - I use outer hosting.
imap_open($this->getServerString(), $this->username, $this->password, $this->options, 1);

Comment: imap_open has /debug parameter which you can use to troubleshoot you problems.There is also /novalidate-cert which ignores certificate problem when connecting by IP.

Comment: I'll try novalidate-cert - I thought You can not use this flag with /ssl.

Comment: Sorry, but where you want to use certificate if not in SSL?Take a look at official PHP documentation on web for function imap_open

Comment: What, in Your opinion is the fastest way to get number of unread messages? I used imap_mailboxmsginfo() but it has to check every catalogue.

Comment: Try this : $result = imap_search($connection, 'UNSEEN'); from this post : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-unread-messages/